# AngularJS.. http.get working, when splitting into its own service module its no longer working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and trying to integrate it within my application. In my first version i used a simple `$http.get` to a .JSON file, which was successful.

The `$http.get` was originally in my controller and i am trying to modularise it by creating a service.

When calling my new service, and displaying to the console, i can see the data in the JSON file is found, however, when showing in my HTML, it is blank.

**My controller:**

```
app.controller("CountriesController", function($scope, $http, countriesService) {

$scope.countries = [];

   countriesService.getCountryData(function(data) {

        $scope.countries = data.countries ;

        console.log(data.countries);            
    });

});
```

**My service:**

```
define([ 'app'], function(app) {
'use strict';

  app.factory('countriesService', function() {
      return {
          getCountryData: function(done) {
            $.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json', done);
          }
      }
  });

});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
  {[{country.name}]}
</li>
```

When viewing in Firebug, i can see the following in my console:

```
[Object { name="Spain"}, Object { name="USA"}, Object { name="France"}]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Update**************************************

Forgot to mention i've changed the way i bind from {{}} to {[{ }]} via:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    }
);
```

**Update**************************************

**My original Controller (which was working to get data and display to front-end HTML):**

```
$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data.countries;
    console.log(data.countries);

 }).error(function(error) {
    alert('An error occured');
});
```

**Update Decorating Controller **************************************

```
require(['app', 'service/myService'], function(app) {
'use strict';

   app.controller("CountriesController", function($scope, $http, countiresService) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is using the jquery `$` i believe. The service should be, with callback invoked inside `then`

```
app.factory('countriesService', function($http) {
      return {
          getCountryData: function(done) {
            $http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json')
               .success(function(data) { done(data);});
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: @Chanermani - I may have spoken too soon, i am getting the error: Error: Unknown provider: countriesServiceProvider <- countriesServiceService

Comment: This is dependency injection error. Make sure there is a service define by name `countriesService`. Why do I see `countriesServiceService` here `Service` is repeated twice.

Comment: @Chanermani - Seems as though in my controller file, i need to decorate it with require(['app', 'service/myService'], function(app) {...... So in essence, im requiring myService.. This that correct?

Comment: added "Update Decorating Controller"

Comment: You are using some on demand script loading library, which i am not much familiar with. But there is a typo there `countiresService`

Comment: Out of interest, in your answer, what does { done(data);}  do?

Comment: `done` is your callback method. `data` is the returned by server. Essentially calling the callback method `done` with parameter data.

Comment: I see, should there be a .error handler to in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. Basically you are trying to initialise your app with asynchronous data that is not ready yet.

My solution was to create a constant with the asynchronous data in the document.ready() function (jQuery) to be injected in your controller. Only there you can set that value to your scope and print it:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initialising constant variable with async data 
    var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

    $http.get('../request.php').then(
        function (response) {     

            menuApp.constant('COUNTRIES', response.data);     
            // Manually bootstrapping the App
            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            });
        }
    );

});

myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', 'COUNTRIES',
    function($scope, COUNTRIES) {

    if (COUNTRIES != undefined) {
        $scope.countries = COUNTRIES;   
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This is not the issue, and you are mixing both jquery and angularjs together, for something that can be done completely in angular.